# Declare a global variable in boo

Tags: boo

As far as I can tell from the [website](http://boo.codehaus.org/Structure+of+a+Boo+Script), the following code should compile to a DLL with a top-level property `Version`:

```
namespace MyLibrary

[Module]
class MainClass:
    public static Version as string

    static def constructor():
        Version = "0.1"
```

This compiles, but if I then enter these commands into `booish`:

```
import MyLibrary
print (Version)
```

then I get "ERROR: Unknown identifier: 'Version'".

Presumably this code worked in an earlier version of the language. I am using 0.9.4.9. What is the correct way to achieve this effect?

(I've noticed that there is an implicit static class `MyVersionModule` in which top-level static methods get placed, but I don't know how to add properties to this either).

Answer (score 0):

In .net there is no way to have methods or fields that are not actually members of a class. Boo hides this somewhat by having the implicit class for the main file in the module (as you noticed) but when importing you still need to access it as a member.

For statics you have to first reference the type then the member so in your example printing the version would be like this:

```
import MyLibrary
print (MainClass.Version)
```

Of course this isn't the 'correct' way to store version information in .net though, which is to use assembly level attributes instead. That would look more like this:

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion("1.0")]

namespace MyLibrary

[Module]
class MainClass:
  pass
```

Then getting the version you would do using reflection, there are a couple of ways to get the assembly but the easiest is to get the Type then it's assembly:

```
import System
import System.Reflection
import MyLibrary

atts = typeof(MainClass).Assembly \
         .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyVersionAttribute), false)

version = (atts[0] as AssemblyVersionAttribute).Version
print(version)
```